# In filter list records of rails_admin gem, Is it possible to make a relationship between filtering fields 'or' instead 'and'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I have installed RailsAdmin gem and I would filter list by associations field.

Is it possible to make a relationship between filtering fields '**or**' instead '**and**' ?!

for example, i would all records that meet the first condition **or** the second condition!

Answer (score 0):

This feature isn't implemented in `ActiveRecord` yet, but it was merged in [this pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16052) and will be released in rails 5 as per [this comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16052#issuecomment-72718557).

You have other options like falling back to arel and do a query like [explained here](https://github.com/rails/arel#more-sophisticated-queries)

Or you could do a worse option, like plucking the id's then adding them in a third query to get an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, if you want a simple array you could do 2 queries and add them to each other.